# How to receive out of line memory using mach messages

Tags: c, macos, ipc, mach

I'm trying to receive a string sent with a complex mach message. More specifically an out of line memory(OOL) message. Unfortunately there is little documentation or examples of OOL mach messages on the internet or in print. For example [http://www.amazon.com/Mac-OS-Internals-Systems-Approach/dp/0321278542](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321278542) has a partial example on page 1091 of sending OOL messages but no example for receiving OOL messages.

When receiving the mach message I don't get an error, ie `mach_msg()` returns success, but the string sent is `NULL` instead of `"123456789"`. So how do I correctly receive data sent in a OOL mach message?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>

static char *string = "123456789";

struct ool_msg
{
    mach_msg_header_t header;
    mach_msg_body_t body;
    mach_msg_ool_descriptor_t data;
    mach_msg_type_number_t count;
};

int main(void)
{
    kern_return_t err;
    struct ool_msg msg;
    struct ool_msg recv_msg;
    mach_msg_header_t *hdr;
    mach_port_t port = MACH_PORT_NULL;

    err = mach_port_allocate(mach_task_self(), MACH_PORT_RIGHT_RECEIVE, &port);
    if(err != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        mach_error("Can't allocate mach port\n", err);
        return (-1);
    }

    err = mach_port_insert_right(mach_task_self(), port, port,
                                 MACH_MSG_TYPE_MAKE_SEND);
    if(err != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        mach_error("Can't insert port right\n", err);
        return (-1);
    }

    hdr = &(msg.header);
    hdr->msgh_bits = MACH_MSGH_BITS(MACH_MSG_TYPE_COPY_SEND, MACH_MSG_TYPE_MAKE_SEND);
    hdr->msgh_bits |= MACH_MSGH_BITS_COMPLEX;
    hdr->msgh_size = sizeof(msg);
    hdr->msgh_local_port = MACH_PORT_NULL;
    hdr->msgh_remote_port = port;

    msg.body.msgh_descriptor_count = 1;
    msg.data.address = string;
    msg.data.size = (mach_msg_size_t)strlen(string) + 1;
    msg.data.deallocate = FALSE;
    msg.data.copy = MACH_MSG_VIRTUAL_COPY;
    msg.data.type = MACH_MSG_OOL_DESCRIPTOR;
    msg.count = msg.data.size;

    err = mach_msg(hdr,
                  MACH_SEND_MSG,
                  hdr->msgh_size,
                  0,
                  MACH_PORT_NULL,
                  MACH_MSG_TIMEOUT_NONE,
                  MACH_PORT_NULL);
    if(err != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        mach_error("Can't send mach msg\n", err);
        return (-1);
    }

    recv_msg.header.msgh_size = sizeof(struct ool_msg);

    err = mach_msg(&recv_msg.header, MACH_RCV_LARGE | MACH_RCV_INTERRUPT,
                   0, sizeof(recv_msg), port,
                   MACH_MSG_TIMEOUT_NONE, MACH_PORT_NULL); 
    if(err != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        mach_error("Can't recieve message\n", err); 
        return (-1); 
    }

    printf("data: %s\n", recv_msg.data.address);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Just a guess. Notice how [much] you're filling in for `msg` [vs. `recv_msg`]. Don't you have to set up more of `recv_msg` before the call? Specifically, preset `recv_msg.data.address = my_receive_buffer` and `recv_msg.data.size = sizeof(my_receive_buffer)`. There may be more of these.

Comment: I'm not sure, in non OOL examples all the receiver does is set the message size which I did.

Comment: For debug, I'd make sure [both] structs have zeroes for any non-set fields [move them from stack to globals or use memset]. I found: http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/mach_msg_descriptor.html From that, for OOL, you may need to set `copy`. Anyway, after the receive call, I'd use gdb to dump the `msg_recv` struct and see what actually got filled in. A little trial and error: start adding recv presets, one-by-one (e.g. `recv_msg.data.type = MACH_MSG_OOL_DESCRIPTOR`) until it works. Without that, how does the recv call know you want OOL?

Comment: Are you sure `mach_msg` returns no error? As your receive buffer is too small! Every message received has a trailer, even if the sent message didn't provide one (in that case the system will generate one for you) and also if you have not requested one (if you request a specific trailer you get what you requested, otherwise you get the default trailer). Your code should fail with an error because your receive buffer is too small.